# Simplest way to comment/uncomment certain lines using command line

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

Is there a way to comment/uncomment a shell/config/ruby script using command line?

for example:

```
$ comment 14-18 bla.conf
$ uncomment 14-18 bla.conf
```

this would add or remove `#` sign on `bla.conf` on line `14` to `18`. Normally I use `sed`, but I must know the contents of those lines and then do a find-replace operation, and that would give a wrong result when the there are more than one needle (and we're only want to replace the N-th one).

Comment: There is an A to this Q titled: [Uncommenting multiple lines of code, specified by line numbers, using vi or vim](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84929/uncommenting-multiple-lines-of-code-specified-by-line-numbers-using-vi-or-vim) which shows many methods for doing this using `sed`, `perl`, etc. Specifically the A by terdon!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

To comment lines 2 through 4 of bla.conf:

```
sed -i '2,4 s/^/#/' bla.conf
```

To make the command that you wanted, just put the above into a shell script called comment:

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -i "$1"' s/^/#/' "$2"
```

This script is used the same as yours with the exception that  the first and last lines are to be separated by a comma rather than a dash.  For example:

```
comment 2,4 bla.conf
```

An uncomment command can be created analogously.

#### Advanced feature

`sed`'s line selection is quite powerful.  In addition to specifying first and last lines by number, it is also possible to specify them by a regex.  So, if you want to command all lines from the one containing `foo` to the one containing `bar`, use:

```
comment '/foo/,/bar/' bla.conf
```

#### BSD (OSX) Systems

With BSD sed, the `-i` option needs an argument even if it is just an empty string.  Thus, for example, replace the top command above with:

```
sed -i '' '2,4 s/^/#/' bla.conf
```

And, replace the command in the script with:

```
sed -i '' "$1"' s/^/#/' "$2"
```

Comment: Are the double `'` after the `-i` option intentional? Didn't need them.

Comment: +1 for considering OSX systems in your response <3

Comment: For some reason I `continued to get a unterminated 's's` Error every time I tried your command. This was because there was a space in-between the lines and the s. Had to remove the space to get it to work `sed -i '2,4s/^/#/' bla.conf`

Answer (score 14):

With GNU sed (to replace the files in place with the `-i` option):

```
sed -i '14,18 s/^/#/' bla.conf
sed -i '14,18 s/^##*//' bla.conf
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create a bash_file with functions to reuse it in your projects

```
#!/bin/bash

# your target file
CONFIG=./config.txt

# comment target
comment() {
  sed -i '' "s/^$1/#$1/" $CONFIG
}

# comment target
uncomment() {
  echo $1
  sed -i '' "s/^#$1/$1/" $CONFIG
}


# Use it so:
uncomment enable_uart
comment arm_freq
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc 'g/^\s*[^#]/s/^/#/' -cx bla.conf
ex -sc 'g/^\s*#/s/#//' -cx bla.conf
```

1. `g` global regex
2. `s` substitute
3. `x` save and close

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

---

***Comment-Out lines:***

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'if (6 <= ++$ <= 8) { put S/^/#/ } else { $_.put };' alpha10.txt

#OR

~$ raku -ne '(6 <= ++$ <= 8) ?? put S/^/#/ !! $_.put;' alpha10.txt

#OR

~$ raku -ne 'put (6 <= ++$ <= 8) ?? S/^/#/ !! $_;' alpha10.txt

#OR

~$ raku -pe 'if (6 <= ++$ <= 8) { s/^/#/ };' alpha10.txt
```

Sample Input:

```
~$ raku -e 'print "a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf\ng\nh\ni\nj\n";' > alpha10.txt
```

Sample Output:

```
a
b
c
d
e
#f
#g
#h
i
j
```

These answers (above AND below) take advantage of Raku's conditional syntax, either `if`/`else` or ternary: "Test `??` True `!!` False". See URLs below for details. Note the chained `<=` inequalities. Also: parens around the conditional are superfluous. And should you encounter quoting difficulties, the `#` octothorpe can be entered as a single-character, bespoke character class via `<[#]>`, (with or without a quantifier).

---

***Uncomment lines:***

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'if (6 <= ++$ <= 8) { put S/^ \s* "#" // } else { $_.put };' alpha10commented.txt

#OR

~$ raku -ne '(6 <= ++$ <= 8) ?? put S/^ \s* "#"// !! $_.put;' alpha10commented.txt

#OR

~$ raku -ne 'put (6 <= ++$ <= 8) ?? S/^ \s* "#" // !! $_;' alpha10commented.txt

#OR

~$ raku -pe 'if (6 <= ++$ <= 8) { s/^ \s* "#" // };' alpha10commented.txt
```

Sample Input:

```
~$ raku -e 'print "a\nb\nc\nd\ne\n#f\n#g\n#h\ni\nj\n";' > alpha10commented.txt
```

Sample Output:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
```

https://docs.raku.org/syntax/if
https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#index-entry-operator_ternary
https://raku.org